# How to style the toolbar in Designer

Tags: codenameone

I have been playing around with the Theme editor but have not been able to style the toolbar correctly. I want to have a solid dark bluish background color with white text but I have only been able to get that effect on the title, the question ball and the settings dots.

The hamburger is white on an almost white background and there is a white top border above the title. I cannot find the setting in the selectors. As you can see the hamburger is barely visible.

[image: screen grab from the designer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIID for the side menu button is `MenuButton`. You can also customize the icon using the theme constant `sideMenuImage`.